# python singleton class decorator

Tags: python, singleton, decorator

I have come across this singleton implementation here: http://blog.amir.rachum.com/post/21850841339/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-python in the first reply.

```
def singleton(cls):
    return cls()

@singleton
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print id(Foo)
    print id(Foo)
```

But I don't understand the inner workings, the decorator returns a class instance, but why the same instance every time ?

Comment: The `singleton` pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system ... example is logging, since you want to log in the same file across the application

Comment: I know what the singleton pattern is, but I don't understand why this particular implementation works like a singleton

Comment: Note this isn't really a singleton pattern, since the user doesn't instantiate the class.  This merely replaces the class with an instance of the class, then the user uses that name as an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rewrite that code to

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

Foo = singleton(Foo)
# which is
Foo = Foo()
```

So here the name of the class is replaced by an instantiation of it. A bit cheesy in my opinion, especially since you can still create new objects of the same class by using `Foo.__class__` and you are messing with the naming schema.

Comment: It is perfectly useless to create classes for singletons in python. This is probably the most awful anti-pattern imported from Java or other C++. Simply create an instance of Foo() at the module level and call it "singleton": singleton = Foo() ... and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

The singleton does that by holding internal state. This state here would probably be an instance of the class. The decorator can be something arbitrary.

Have a look at this:

http://hairysun.com/downloads/DecoratorHandout.pdf

```
class Decorator(object):
    # in __init__ set up state
    def __call__(self, function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw): # 1.
            print "before func"
            result = function(*args, **kw) # 2.
            print "after func"
            return result
        return wrapper # 3.

>>> decorator2 = Decorator()
>>> @decorator2
... def nothing(): pass
```

The decorator is essentially a function that

1. Defines a function
2. That calls the function that you passed in
3. Returns the newly 'wrapped' function to be called later

The surrounding class (here: the decorator) could do something like this:

```
class Singleton(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.instance = None

     def __call__(self, function):
         @functools.wraps(function)
         def wrapper(*args, **kw):
             if self.instance is None:
                self.instance = function(*args, **kw)
             return self.instance
         return wrapper
```

I did not run the code, but I assume this is in general how it works. If there is no instance available create one. If one is available, don't create a new one - return the single old one instead. One might probably want to check for other properties of the callable before using this in production.